# ASP.Net v4 site ...Best way to save something on the server and return nothing

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

Is there a way using the UpdatePanel to have it SAVE data on the server ..but NOT return any HTML so the page does NOT even reload Partially?

Like a total ASYNC event that gets disregarded after it executes on the server?

Answer (score 1):

The way is to return the status code 204, but there is the possibility the update panel save this post back on view state and because is not going to get back the replay, on the second post you get again this post command with the new one...

```
    // this is for IIS7
    Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
    // sending this response you archive what you ask
    Response.Status = "204 No Content";
    Response.StatusCode = 204;
    Response.End();
```

anyway, make a try to see if this make your work. If this not work, you other option is to make a custom handler and you call a link to that handler passing the parameters you like, ether this way, ether using ajax.